# How to make this background stretch throughout the whole website

Tags: html, css

Hi Guys I have this site:

http://www.ryansammut.com/orijen/

Basically so far I managed to make the top part strech as a background, now I need to make the other parts too. I'm not sure how to do it, so I'm asking for ideas how this would be done best, keeping the positioning all relative and the background image would adjust according to the needed content area.

PS. This is only needed for resolutions greater than 1280px, so zoom out if you need to see what's happening.

Comment: To be clear, the dark banner is what you want (and have achieved), and you want the "peach" and bottom dark banner to do the same? Would that be accurate?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do.
The top part is fixed in size, and not stretching either.

Answer (score 1):

You can not stretch those elements because they are contained in a div named 'wrapper', which has a maximum width of 1280px.

add the following properties to : header, contentbackground, and footer:

```
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```

this will make sure the elements are centered.

then remove the width property from #wrapper, and add the background to it so it reads as follows :

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/contentBG.png);
}
```

However, now we won't see the horizontal stretch of the header anymore, so we need to move #header above #wrapper.

```
<div id="header">
 ...
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying it out atm, so far it's ok still have minor issues.

Comment: be careful though, i have no idea if any of those pages differ much in layout, and you might mess those up when you change #wrapper.
Any changes you make in the HTML here should likely be made on every different page as well.

Comment: yes I know, it's giving me some problems to be honest, with the layout now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use tables, use DIVs only.
2. No need to include FlowPlayer script two times.
3. I dont see you use JQuery (no need to include that).
4. Replace Dreamweaver's rollover images with proper CSS:

.item {background: image.jpg}
.item:hover {background: image_rollover.jpg}

1. Get sprite images (you can read here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

As the original question... you have to use two DIVs for each "row", like this:

```
#header_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: header_backgroud.jpg;
}
#menu_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: menu_backgroud.jpg;
}
#content_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: content_backgroud.jpg repeat center top;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1260px;
}

<div id="header_wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    --- header content ---
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menu_wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    --- menu content ---
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    --- page content ---
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so remove the wrapper class, and work with 3 wrappers (header, content, footer) and use div and class for each should solve things?

Comment: This sounds like an easier approach than what i was doing, but would still require the margin-left and margin-right of all 'wrapped' classes to be set to 'auto'

Comment: @Timothy Groote This is what I have atm, PS: I only did the contact page so far because it has no text in it, still didn't manage to center it. http://www.ryansammut.com/orijen/contact.html

Comment: Ok, so far so good, but : margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto do not center an object if it has no width set. make sure the following divs are 1280px wide : #header and #footer.
I don't know what's up with the middle section, but try to avoid adding two divs with the same classname inside each other

Comment: @Timothy but aren't we setting the width in the .header instead of in #header ?

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, the width should be set in #header, you are right.

Comment: @Timothy Groote I used something like this to fix it, what do you think? 

#footer
{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 293px;
 background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
}

.footer
{
 position: relative;
 width: 1280px; 
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -640px;
}

Comment: `position:relative; left:50%; margin-left:-640px;` sounds a little complex for something that can be accomplished with `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`, i'm also unsure if there will be problems in different browsers, or when people resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the structure to something like this:

```
<div id="header">
   <div>
     <ul>Nav</ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
   <div>Content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS could look something like this:

```
div#header { width: 100%; background: black; }
  div#header div { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(...); }
div#mainContent { width: 100%; background: url(...); }
  div#mainContent div { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }
div#footer { width: 100%; background: black; }
  div#footer div { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

It is fast written, hope you can see the idea? I can't see why you would go with position absolute or relative. Use margin: 0 auto; to center divs instead :)

Comment: what does div#footer div do then? I Mean is it like an inner div?

Comment: @Ryan, it is like the header and mainContent div. They function as containers. So you have 3 main divs containing the whole page. The footer div in my example has you're bottom form with logo and all. I can suggest you try it out, and then see what happends step by step :)